# Захват текста после точки в С#

Tags: c#, файлы, форматирование

Пользователь вводит адреса сайтов. Все сайты находящиеся НЕ в доменах `.com` и `.net` внести в файл.
Как отделить домен со всего сайта? Иначе: Как получить текст после последней точки в предложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужно построить Uri:

```
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
```

Теперь, вам нужно определить, какого типа Uri вам достался:

```
if (uri.Scheme != "http" && uri.Scheme != "https")
{
    // то вам достался не http-адрес, сделайте что-то
```

```
if (uri.HostNameType != UriHostNameType.Dns)
{
    // то у вас адрес не с доменным именем, а например с айпишником или ещё более странный,
    // сделайте что-то
```

Теперь у вас есть имя хоста:

```
var host = uri.Host;
```

Вы можете его разбить по точке на части:

```
var hostParts = host.Split('.')
```

и анализировать как вам нравится. Не забудьте, что кроме `.com` есть ещё домены `.com.ru` или `.co.uk` (именно `co`!), так что вам понадобится скорее всего не только последняя компонента.

Comment: Сделал, как Вы сказали. Не работает, не распознаёт `line`
В чём ошибка: http://goo.gl/S0Eutc ?

Comment: @Дмитрий: В каком смысле не распознаёт? А что в этот момент в `line`?

Comment: Считанная строка из документа, в который до этого внесли сайт

Comment: @Дмитрий: ну да, а что именно в этой строке? Какое конкретное содержимое строки?

Comment: @Дмитрий: И что значит «не распознаёт»?

Comment: В строке сайт. И считывается он верно: http://goo.gl/KwxKBv

Comment: @Дмитрий: Окей, а что в этом случае означает «не распознаёт»? У вас же и нет никакого анализирующего кода в примере.

Comment: А разве `uri.Host` не должен быть `.com`?
Тут вообще конструкция сложная, было бы проще сделать через парсинг строчки отдельными элементами разделёнными точкой

Comment: @Дмитрий: Нет, конечно, это же хост. Парсинг строчки не поможет вам отловить более сложные случаи. Например, `127.0.0.1`. Ну увидите вы, что после последней точки не com и не net, это ж вам не поможет. Без `Uri` получается только тыкаться вслепую. А ещё может быть `google.com/path.inside/?query.ru`, как парсить будете?

Comment: Такое тыканье мне и нужно. Там ситуаций с localhost и углублённым ссылкам не будет :)

Answer (score 2):

Вас интересует функция [System.String.LastIndexOf(Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0w96zd3d.aspx), она вернёт вам ближайший от конца строки индекс символа в строке.